# Google Maps Marker Not Displaying From Firebase

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

GoogleMaps markers are not displaying after I query Firebase where location coordinates are stored as geopoints (latitude and longitude) under the collection 'markers.'

I have followed the changelog on the Flutter GoogleMaps plugin where markers where made as their own widget, without any success. I connect to the database using Firebase.instance and query through 'markers.' The for loops attempts to return the relevant information. populateClients and initMarkers are the the methods that are created to add the markers to the map, using the process described in the GoogleMaps recent marker update.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

 class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreen();
 }

    class _FirstScreen extends State<FirstScreen> {
   GoogleMapController mapController;

  var currentLocation;

  var clients = [];

   Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    populateClients();
    Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currloc){
    setState(() {
     currentLocation = currloc;
      });
    });
  }


  populateClients() {

    Firestore.instance.collection('markers').getDocuments().then((docs)    
 {
      if(docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        for(int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; i++) {
         //clients.add(docs.documents[i].data);
         initMarker(docs.documents[i].data,     
  docs.documents[i].documentID);
           }
         }
      });
    }

  void initMarker(client, markerRef) {
       var markerIDVal = markerRef;
      final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIDVal);

       //new marker

      final Marker marker = Marker(
        position: LatLng(client['location'].latitude,   
 client['location'].longitude),
        markerId: markerId,
      );

      setState(() {
        // adding a new marker to map
        markers[markerId] = marker;
     });
 }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return currentLocation == null ? Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
):
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition:
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
          currentLocation.longitude), zoom: 17),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
    ),
  ],
);
  }



  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
   setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }


 }
```

The markers would display on the geolocation points that are stored in Firebase.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your `populateClients` call to see if you are getting data back from Firebase? It looks like what you are doing should work, but it's hard to know what's going wrong without being able to step through the code.

Comment: This help tremendously; I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. The error showed I was not calling the Firebase API correctly. It turned out, my API key was incorrect. After an update of the API key in the AndroidManifest file, I was able to successfully query it.

Comment: I'm glad that helped solve your issue.